# DirectX - Sharing resource handle among different threads

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, directx, dxgi

I created a texture with flags `D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED_NTHANDLE | D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED_KEYEDMUTEX` as described in the documentation to share it among different devices (I have multiple threads concurring to read that resource once created)

```
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC textureDesc;
textureDesc.Width = Width;
textureDesc.Height = Height;
textureDesc.MipLevels = 1;
textureDesc.ArraySize = 1;
textureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
textureDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
textureDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
textureDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
textureDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET;
textureDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
textureDesc.MiscFlags = D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED_NTHANDLE | D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED_KEYEDMUTEX;

ID3D11Texture2D *returnTexture;
d3d11Device->CreateTexture2D(&textureDesc, NULL, &returnTexture);

IDXGIResource1 *sharedResource;
returnTexture->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIResource1), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&sharedResource));

HANDLE shareHandle;
sharedResource->CreateSharedHandle(nullptr, DXGI_SHARED_RESOURCE_READ | DXGI_SHARED_RESOURCE_WRITE, nullptr, &shareHandle);

// acquire the mutex and copy data into the texture from another one
// release the mutex
```

After populating this texture (I acquire its `IDXGIKeyedMutex`, copy data into it and then release the mutex) I pass the `shareHandle` around multiple threads.

Each thread might occasionally need to transfer memory on the CPU from that texture

```
ID3D11Device1 *d3d11Device1;
d3d11Device->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID3D11Device1), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&d3d11Device1));

HANDLE shareHandle = getSharedHandleSomewhere();
IDXGIResource1 *sharedResource;
d3d11Device1->OpenSharedResource1(shareHandle, __uuidof(IDXGIResource1), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&sharedResource));

// acquire the mutex and write the contents into another staging texture
// release the mutex

CloseHandle(shareHandle);
```

All `HRESULT` error codes (excluded from the code above for clarity reasons) return no errors, but after a few frames `OpenSharedResource1` on one of the threads fails with `DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_REMOVED` (and I'm quite sure no physical monitor is ever removed).

What could be the cause of this? I also tried duplicating the handle with `DuplicateHandle` one per each thread but that doesn't fix the problem either (the handles are all opaque 'references' to the same resource right I suppose).
Could that be that I can only open the shared resource *once* instead of doing it multiple times?

Comment: The `DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_REMOVED` is about the ` video card`, not the monitor ;-)

Comment: HAve you used `D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_SINGLETHREADED` in the device creation flags?

Comment: You typically enable D3D11 debug layer to get related diagnostics.

Comment: @Stefan no, the flags were just 0

Comment: @RomanR. I added the debug layer flag to every context creation but stderr is sadly empty

Comment: You need to look at debug output, either Debug Output window when running from Visual Studio, or DebugView app capturing that output when you runs your app standalone.

Comment: @RomanR. it's empty :(

Comment: @RomanR. it's weird, it seems like I can't `OpenSharedResource1` a resource even from a duplicated handle if that same resource was `OpenSharedResource1`-opened before from a different thread

Comment: The API is in general operational, if you follow the lines of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee913554 You might want to either get debug output working, or post a runnable code (not just snippet pieces) to exhibit the issue.

Comment: Why do you QueryInterface itself for the ID3D11Device1?